# Can I combine Hex & Greenflame Blade in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

Since Greenflame Blade is a 1 action cantrip and so can be used in conjuntion with a spell that can be cast as a bonus action, can I cast Hex (a bonus spell that requires concentration) initially then follow it with Greenflame Blade, and so combine the damage from both? Or does casting Greenflame Blade interrupt concentration on Hex so the Hex damage cannot be added?

Answer (score 9):

## Yes you can combine them.

There are only three **general** ways to lose concentration *(PHB, p. 203)*:

- Casting another spell that requires concentration *(this includes spells, with 
  longer casting times (PHB, p. 202))*
- Taking damage *(and failing the saving throw)*
- Being incapacitated or killed

*Other ways to lose concentration are explicitly mentioned in the relevant game feature, for example, in the **Earthquake** spell, and in the Barbarians **Rage** feature.*

*The DM can also decide that certain circumstances require you to succeed on a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration, as mentioned in the PHB on p. 204*

---

*Hex* is a 1st-level bonus-action spell and *Green-Flame Blade* is a cantrip with the casting time of 1 action. As you already mentioned **you are able to cast them both**.

**Will you lose concentration on *Hex* when casting *Green-Flame Blade*?**

You are neither taking damage nor are you incapacitated/killed when casting *Green-Flame Blade*, so we can exclude those causes. Since the **casting time is 1 action** it does not count as a spell with a *longer casting time* as for *PHB p. 202*. The **duration of *Green-Flame Blade* is instantaneous, requiring no concentration.** There is no reason for you to lose concentration on *Hex*.

---

The bonus damage from *Hex* will only affect the cursed target though.

Comment: It's worth a mention that this is not only allowed but a potentially very good method of attack for a Bladelock (before Extra Attack) or even for a shillelagh tomelock, although you can't cast shillelagh and hex in the same turn.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker thanks, added those to my answer.